# Make mat-autocomplete of input visible on button click(angular)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to activate the mat-autocomplete panel of input visible when we click on the button.

```
<div class="filter">
    <button  mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="showFilter()" >Add Filter</button>
    <div [class.open]="isOpen" class="filter-menu">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <input type="text" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" >
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" >
                <mat-option *ngFor="let filter of filter" [value]="filter.filterName" (click)="filterFunc(filter.filterName)">
                  {{filter.filterName}}
                </mat-option>
              </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `*ngIf` to show or not show it?

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-overview-example.css'],
})
export class AutocompleteOverviewExample {
  filter: any[] = [
    { filterName: 'test' },
    { filterName: 'other filter' },
    { filterName: 'third filter' },
  ];
  isOpen: boolean = false;

  showFilter() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }

  filterFunc(value: string) {
    console.log('do something ', value);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
<button  mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="showFilter()" >Add Filter</button>
<div *ngIf="isOpen" class="filter-menu">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <input type="text" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" >
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" >
            <mat-option *ngFor="let filter of filter" [value]="filter.filterName" (click)="filterFunc(filter.filterName)">
              {{filter.filterName}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
</div>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-of9a4k?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html

Comment: the issue we auto-complete gets visible only when input is active which happens only when the page is loaded. when we click the button the input gets visible but is not activated which makes auto-complete hidden. I need something which on button click display input and auto-complete panel open together without addition click on input to activate

Comment: Please have a look at this. I copied your code over, seems to work for me. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-of9a4k?file=app%2Fautocomplete-overview-example.html

Comment: yeah input gets loaded onclick but autocomplete panel gets visible after we click on input. i want autocomplete panel visible without clicking on the input

Comment: In the original question you asked for the opposite? Then take `<mat-form-field>` out of the `<div *ngIf>` and raise it one level higher into the parenting div?

Comment: autocomplete panel still does not open automatically when input becomes visible